# Regarding Ubuntu Software Application

Tags: 20.04, snap-store

I have recently dual booted my windows with ubuntu 20.04. I just wanted to know whether the ubuntu software is snap-store. I also heard of an other store called gnome-software. What is the difference between these three and which one is pre-installed with the ubuntu installation? There seems to be no clear explanation between these three and about the above question. I wanted to know because my software center doesn't load apps when I click on the categories shown there. I want to completely uninstall and reinstall the store if that works.

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231557/how-do-i-reinstall-ubuntu-software-in-ubuntu-20-04-lts-version

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Has 'Ubuntu Software' been renamed to 'Snap Store'?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1252134/has-ubuntu-software-been-renamed-to-snap-store) And https://askubuntu.com/questions/769129/what-is-the-difference-between-gnome-software-and-ubuntu-software

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu Software indeed is "Snap Store" (`snap-store`). It is the default in a fresh install of Ubuntu, and is in fact a customized version of Gnome Software from the Gnome developpers.

You can remove and reinstall `snap-store`. You may also safely remove `snap-store` and install Gnome Software instead. How is detailed in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231557/how-do-i-reinstall-ubuntu-software-in-ubuntu-20-04-lts-version). In addition, you can install support for snap by installing the plugin:

```
sudo apt install gnome-software-plugin-snap
```

If you like flatpak, which is available by default in the Ubuntu derived distribution Linux Mint, you can [set that up too](https://flatpak.org/setup/Ubuntu/). Support for flatpak in Gnome Software is provided by the plugin:

```
sudo apt install gnome-software-plugin-flatpak
```